# How can I tell if a bumblebee left my apartment or if it's still hiding somewhere?

Tags: home, insects

A bumblebee got into my apartment through an open door. We lost track of it after a few minutes, and it may have flown outside. How can we be sure?

[image]

We closed the door it came in to keep other critters out. We searched the whole apartment including each window and a vase of cut flowers. We have not heard or seen it for about 45 minutes. Do bumblebees stay "grounded" for that long during daytime hours, or do they only land for a minute or two and then keep flying? If they pause for a only couple minutes then I'll be confident it's gone because I haven't seen it, but if they stay still for long periods of time then it's possible it may still be lurking and I just haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The bumblebee which strayed into your apartment was a worker bumblebee. The workers  **need** to work. A bumblebee would not stay grounded for 45 minutes in the middle of the day. The only reason a bumble bee would stay inside like that would be it got trapped in something and couldn't leave-meaning it would die.

Comment: So what you're saying is that if I don't see or hear it for 10-15 minutes, it has either left or it died. Thanks! Upvote.

Comment: They usually take longer than 15 minutes to die when they are trapped,but it hasn't come out for 15 minutes,and isn't helped, it will just die.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's gone in your case, but when other insects come inside you should either catch them in a cup and take them outside. You could also gently coax them towards an open door or window.

Comment: I'm sure it's gone too - I haven't seen or heard it for almost 24 hours. Typically I would catch them in a cup and take them out. We had just lost track of this one and didn't want a surprise!

Comment: What surprise would you get if the bumblebee was gone?

Comment: I would get no surprise if it was gone. If it was _not_ gone, I might receive the unpleasant surprise of a bee sting!